# Can't install PyAL in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.5, openal

I wanted to use OpenAL in Python, therefore I tried to install **PyAL** through the Pycharm project settings.

I got the error message:

```
No matching distribution found for PyAL
s the requirement PyAL (from version: )
```

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

**Reference:**

- Pycharm Community Edition 2016.1.4
- pip version 8.1.2
- Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

There is no source or binary distribution for [PyAL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAL)

Maybe you should download it from [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-al/downloads)

The homepage sais:

> PyAL is easy to install and integrate within your own projects. Just follow Python's standard procedure of installing packages or look for a prebuilt package for your operating system or distribution.

Unfortunately this is not true. The only way to install PyAL is to download the [source](https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-al/downloads) and run the setup.py

```
python setup.py install
```